# Can't find an implicit `SchemaMeta` for type

Tags: scala, cassandra, quill.io

I wrote this simple application using Quill library to query Cassandra

**QuillSample.scala**

```
import java.util.UUID
import io.getquill._
import scala.concurrent.ExecutionContext.Implicits.global
object QuillSample extends App {
   lazy val ctx = new CassandraSyncContext[SnakeCase]("ctx")
   import ctx._
   val getAllRows = quote {
      query[Movies]
   }
   val result = ctx.run(getAllRows)
   println(result)
}
case class Movies(uUID: UUID,
                  avgRating: Float,
                  genres: Set[String],
                  name: String,
                  releaseDate: java.util.Date,
                  videoReleaseDate: java.util.Date)
```

**build.sbt**

```
name := "QuillSample"
version := "1.0"
scalaVersion := "2.12.0"
libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
   "io.getquill" % "quill-cassandra_2.11" % "1.0.0"
)
```

**application.properties**

```
ctx.keyspace=movielens_small
ctx.preparedStatementCacheSize=1000
ctx.session.contactPoint=192.168.1.169
ctx.session.withPort=9042
ctx.session.queryOptions.consistencyLevel=LOCAL_QUORUM
ctx.session.withoutMetrics=true
ctx.session.withoutJMXReporting=false
ctx.session.maxSchemaAgreementWaitSeconds=1
ctx.session.addressTranslater=com.datastax.driver.core.policies.IdentityTranslator
```

This returns a compile time error

```
Error:(14, 12) Can't find an implicit `SchemaMeta` for type `com.abhi.Movies`
      query[Movies]
```

Based on the documentation given here

https://github.com/getquill/quill/blob/master/CASSANDRA.md

I am not sure of what other code is needed to satisfy the missing implicit.

Comment: there is not enough code here to give a proper answer, the implict errors comes when there is no available implict variable in the given scope. From the code you have shown so far, there is no sign of implict being required

Comment: i have edited my question and i added a link to my github code repo. you will find the entire code and sbt file there.

Comment: Have you tried switching to Scala version 2.11.8? What happens then...?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Quill does not yet support Scala 2.12. Track [this PR](https://github.com/getquill/quill/pull/617) for the progress.

Change `scalaVersion`:

```
scalaVersion := "2.11.8"
```

Also you have to use snapshot dependency because of [this fix](https://github.com/getquill/quill/pull/614) that was made after 1.0.0 release:

```
resolvers ++= Seq(
  Resolver.sonatypeRepo("snapshots")
)

libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
  "io.getquill" %% "quill-cassandra" % "1.0.2-SNAPSHOT"
)
```

Next you have to implement custom encoder and decoder for `scala.collection.Set[T]`:

```
trait Encoders {
  this: CassandraSessionContext[_] =>

  implicit def setEncoder[T](implicit t: ClassTag[T]): Encoder[Set[T]] =
    encoder((index, value, row) => row.setSet(index, value.asJava, t.runtimeClass.asInstanceOf[Class[T]]))
}

trait Decoders {
  this: CassandraSessionContext[_] =>

  implicit def setDecoder[T](implicit t: ClassTag[T]): Decoder[Set[T]] =
    decoder((index, row) => row.getSet(index, t.runtimeClass.asInstanceOf[Class[T]]).asScala.toSet)
}
```

And mix it in your context:

```
lazy val ctx = new CassandraSyncContext[SnakeCase]("ctx") with Encoders with Decoders
```

Possibly you will get a warning:

> Class javax.annotation.Nullable not found - continuing with a stub.

To fix it add following dependency:

```
libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
  "com.google.code.findbugs" % "jsr305" % "3.0.1"
)
```

Answer (score -1):

so looks like you don't have a SchemaMeta that is capable of constructing `com.abhi.Movies` so you need to specify one explicitly

```
implicit val movieSchemaMeta = schemaMeta[com.abhi.Movies](....)
```

Comment: and what should be inside that?

Comment: @KnowsNotMuch like `implicit val petSchemaMeta: SchemaMeta[Pet] = schemaMeta[Pet]("pets")` https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78095211/zio-quill-cant-find-implicit-schemameta-for-type-models-pet